# Connecting to MySQL database from Visual Studio COBOL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, cobol

I'm a newbie when it comes to server based SQL. I'm trying to write a small utility for my own use, in Windows. I've downloaded MySQL and created a COBOL program in Visual Studio. I can connect VS to the example database (sakila) using Server Explorer. I can see tables in the window, and when I name a valid one in the COBOL I can get a clean compile, so VS is obviously 'seeing it'. However, I can't connect to the service when I run. I get a -19703 sql code on the SQL 'connect' statement, and the subsequent statement fails also.

```
move "sakila" to datname-arr
move length of "sakila" to datname-len
move "Allan" to username-arr
move length of "Allan" to username-len
move "password" to userpass-arr.
move length of "password" to userpass-len
exec sql connect :username identified by :userpass using :datname end-exec.
```

That's where I get the -19703. The user is valid and the password correct. The SQL preprocessor is OpenESQL, directive DBMAN = ODBC. The associated message is 'Data source name not found and no default driver specified', which may be self explanatory but I'm unsure how to rectify.

Comment: There is no Visual Studio COBOL. I guess you meant "MicroFocus COBOL for Visual Studio 2012", do you?

The error seems to tell you that you did not created the data source name. When using ODBC you should have created one (specifying the actual driver used and at least the server) via `%windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe` (either for the current user or (started as admin) for the system).
Hint: If you have a 32-bit COBOL app and run on a 64-bit OS start `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` instead.

I guess the `datname-arr` should include the DSN name, not the DB name.

Comment: Thanks for your help Simon. To be fair, 'VisualStudio' is the name on the App list, and on the opening screen, and on the top bar - one could be forgiven for thinking that's where one was! But yes, I'd downloaded the ODBC drivers but was obviously (with hindsight) pointing to the wrong one, as well as being mistaken about what counted as 'db name'. I downloaded both the 32 and 64 bit versions, and ran via SysWOW64 as suggested, creating a connection. I have still been unable to connect using variables, or by generating a connection string, but I was able to connect via prompt, so that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to tell you that you did not created the data source name (DSN).

When using ODBC you should have created a data source name (this way specifying the actual driver used and at least the server) via `%windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe` (either for the current user or - started as admin - for the system).

Hint: If you have a 32-bit COBOL app and run on a 64-bit OS start `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` instead. I guess the `datname-arr` should include the DSN name, not the DB name.

Answer (score 0):

The value  [-19703](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.studee60win%2FHCOMDBSASSS003.html) is documented as "Could not make connection."

It looks like you are using "[Format 2](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.enterprisedeveloper.eclipsewin%2FHRDBRHESQL07.html&resultof=%22%73%71%6C%22%20%22%63%6F%6E%6E%65%63%74%22%20)", I find it
easier to use "Format 6" and setup your DSN (like Simon says above).